# Есть ли более удобный способ считать числа, которые подаются на одной строке, в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Предположим, что на вход некоторой программе подаются целые числа `a` и `b`. Проблема в том, что они подаются на одной строке, разделённые пробелом, поэтому привычный код `a, b = int(input()), int(input())` не работает. Можно воспользоваться таким кодом:

```
my_list = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
a, b = my_list[0], my_list[1]
```

Однако можно ли организовать ввод без генерации списка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно.

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

Да и с циклом это тоже делается тоже в одну строку.

```
a, b = (int(i) for i in input().split())
```

(Заметьте, это не список, а генератор, значит лишнюю память не потребляет)

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Нужно делать вот так:

```
a, b = input().split()
```

И всё хорошо работает. Конечно, со списком, но гораздо короче.

Comment: только в a и b теперь строки, а не числа

Comment: Ну это я знаю как исправить

Comment: @vlados155 не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Не за что, был рад помочь)